# How to implement setters on Ecto models (or Elixir structs)

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm coming from a Rails mindset and am used to adding lots of setters to ActiveRecord models to trim/lowercase strings (e.g. email addresses) or normalize phone numbers to use "-" as separators.  I like the setter method because it keeps code that modifies the record DRY.  Is this possible with Elixir/Ecto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, there is no mechanism. The best you can do is to create a function like:

```
User.normalize(%User{}, conn.params["user"])
```

Right now, we are planning to move this code to custom types. So for example you implement an e-mail type that knows how to properly cast and normalize the data, and casting would work on Ecto queries and when assigning field values.

Comment: Custom types would be very cool, I'm also going to look into making my own Repo crud functions.

Comment: We are launching v0.5.0 today and it will include custom types!

Comment: changeset docs via test file: https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/blob/93f70870a474df3e6dbd590e7d5d10b7ddc27dd9/test/ecto/changeset_test.exs

Comment: What about the classic fullname to first_name and last_name setter? I don't think custom types handle it, do they?